# Exponentiation of fixed-point numbers (i.e., a^b) in Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I already know how to calculate x^n, where x is a floating point number and n is an integer. However, I want to implement a price curve, using the formula:

```
y = 0.5 * (x^1.5)
```

To do this, I need to be able to do exponentiation where the power is a floating-point (or fixed-point) value. How can I do this in Solidity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solidity does not offer built-in math functions, therefore you must use a library.

Paul Berg's [PRB-math](https://github.com/hifi-finance/prb-math) library provides fixed-point mathematics operations for Solidity.

Comment: Thanks for the shout out, Mikko! Related links: [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-math-libraries-are-available-in-solidity) and [Is there any efficient way to compute the exponentiation of a fraction and an integer?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/97535/24693).